# Limitation List Services Bluetooth Low Energy Central

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a central application (C #) that consume a Peripheral application services Bluetooh Low Energy (BLE). From the peripheral application services 100 are provided. But in Central application (Windows) only 40 services are listed. This is a technical limitation of Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) layer of Windows? Has anyone experienced this?